# Add the "iCloud" entitlement to your App ID

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Been trying to fix this for the past hour.

This is what the problem is
[image]
But when I go into the Apple member centre it states its been added.
[image]

The ID's match. Bundles match. When I go to https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/ I can also find the container that I've set. Not sure what the problem is.

I have manually disabled the containers in the member centre as well as disabled cloudkit altogether.  When I click the 'Fix Issues' button, it turns on cloudkit and automatically adds the container in the member centre.  Still, the error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed - turns out I need to register a device to add the entitlement.  Plugged in my phone and changed my device to my iPhone on xcode.